# How to speed up this slider?

Tags: css

How to cut the slide transition animation time in half?
I want to reduce the delay of animations between slides
`css`

```
.container_slider_css {
        margin: 50px auto;
        width: 1427px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      .photo_slider_css {
        position: absolute;
        animation: round 9s infinite;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      @keyframes round {
        25% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        40% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      img:nth-child(1) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
      }

      img:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 3s;
      }

      img:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: 0s;
      }
```

`html`

```
<div class="container_slider_css">
    <img class="photo_slider_css" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f4/d2/96/f4d2961b652880be432fb9580891ed62.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="photo_slider_css" src="https://funart.pro/uploads/posts/2021-04/1618119326_16-p-kotiki-obnimashki-zhivotnie-krasivo-foto-16.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="photo_slider_css" src="https://cs11.pikabu.ru/post_img/2019/02/04/12/1549312329147951618.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```

Comment: Adjust the relevant second value? (Probably `9s`, but it's not clear what exactly you want to change)

Comment: @DBS I want to reduce the delay between slides

Comment: Have you tried just halving the second values? If that's not working, we may need a working example so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The slider is built in such a way that each image is animated with a time delay relative to the others. By cutting the overall animation time and delay time in half, we make transitions faster.

```css
.container_slider_css {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 1427px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.photo_slider_css {
  position: absolute;
  animation: round 9s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes round {
  27% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_slider_css">
  <img class="photo_slider_css" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f4/d2/96/f4d2961b652880be432fb9580891ed62.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="photo_slider_css" src="https://funart.pro/uploads/posts/2021-04/1618119326_16-p-kotiki-obnimashki-zhivotnie-krasivo-foto-16.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="photo_slider_css" src="https://cs11.pikabu.ru/post_img/2019/02/04/12/1549312329147951618.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what has changed in the code would be helpful rather than just paste the code and dip :)

Comment: @Andrei Fedorov I want to reduce the delay between slides

Comment: @node_modules the slider is built in such a way that each image is animated with a time delay relative to the others. By cutting the overall animation time and delay time in half, we make transitions faster.

Comment: I imagine node_modules knows that, they were pointing out that you should really add that detail to your answer.

Comment: @Капуста I have edited my answer. so the speed of transitions will approximately double

Comment: Updated the answer properly for you.